# Add DateTime Input to Database Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I'm creating a datetime picker using code

```
<div class='input-group date'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker'/> 
                    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        viewMode: 'years'
        });
    });
  </script>
```

which allows me to create a datetime input. For the backend code, I am able to add fields to the database for asp:textbok's, asp:labels etc, but not for this input.
Here is an example of others I am adding

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobList", jobList.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobCriteria", jobCriterta.Text);
```

When I try to do this for datetime, the option for the ID=datetimepicker does not appear and I'm not able to add whatever datetime is in that input to the database.

Cheers in advance for any help I'm sure it's simple!

Comment: Try adding name='datetimepicker' in your input html tag.

Comment: Add runat atrribute in your date  input control ... runat="server"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access an html control in the back end you need to give the attribute `runat="server"` along with the tag definition.

```
<input type='text' runat="server" class="form-control" id='datetimepicker'/>
```

Then change your script as like this:

```
$("#<%=datetimepicker.ClientID%>").datetimepicker({
        viewMode: 'years'
        });
```

After adding this to the tag you will get `datetimepicker` in the back end. and you can access it's value to do the rest of operations. and one more suggestion use [`.Parameters.Add()` instead for `Parameters.AddWithValue()`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Thank you for this I was able to access it. However, it stopped the jquery from working

Comment: brilliant, thank you. Quickly, why would you suggest .add() instead of .AddWithValue()?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the input tag with TextBox server control.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="datetimepicker" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Remember to set ClientIDMode as "Static" to make sure jQuery code can find the textbox correctly. Then the backend C# code can also use this textbox as web control object.

Comment: thanks for this although an error appears saying "the field datetimepicker's type system.web.ui.htmlinputtext is not compatible with the type of control system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox

Comment: This should be because Visual Studio did not change the type of datetimepicker to WebControls.TextBox in the backgroud. Switch the editor of ASPX page from Source to Design should trigger the change and then your can compile your code correctly.